# Invalid page in communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

FYI, We tried to navigate to VF page from lightning component in community using navigateToURL. Logged in user as System Administrator.
But navigation failed and showing "Invalid page" error.

> Here we enabled the below things : Available for Lightning Experience,
>   Lightning Communities, and the mobile app Enabled Visualforce Page
>   Access

Here's my code. Any advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**NavigateToVfPage.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Navigate VF" onclick="{! c.navigateVF }" />
</aura:component>
```

**NavigateToVfPageController.js**

```
({
    navigateVF : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({ 
            "url": "/apex/NavigateUI" 
        }).fire();
    }
})
```

**NaviagteUI.VF**

```
<apex:page >
    <button type="button" onclick="navigateBack()">
        navigate back
    </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function navigateBack() {
        console.log("navigate to previous");
    }

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: what is the community URL where you have your VF page, that is wehre you should be pointing to with your event.

Comment: This is the community url: `https://examextension-developer-edition.ap4.force.com/ExAM`. All we are trying to do here is to navigate to a VF page onclick of a button.

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening a visualforce page from my lightning component and it works for me.Why don't you first try opening a visuaforce page in your community through your browser url to know it has required permission to be accessed in community.You can do it using following:

```
instanceurlofCommunity/namespace[if any]/apex/visualforce page.
```

**Try removing '/s' if  you are not able to open the visualforce page above**

this is the url which I get when I try to open the visualforce page in my community from lightning component:

```
instanceurlofCommunity/s/sfdcpage/%2Fapex%2FMap
```

I used the following and it works fine:

```
 navigateToVf : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({ 
            "url": "/apex/Map" 
        }).fire();
    }
```

Comment: We observed the same thing. We don't want to hardcode `sfdcpage` in the url since the piece will be part of a managed package. Is there's any documentation which you could point us to which talks about how the VF url should look like in the lightning community.

Comment: @Praveen The one way mentioned above using force:navigateToURl is the correct way to navigate to visualforce page inside the lightning cmponent.I used the same and it worked for me.I have edited the answer you can refer it.

Comment: @ishaarora95 We tried same in our lightning component but we are getting this url `instanceurlofCommunity/s/apex/visualforce page` instead of `instanceurlofCommunity/s/sfdcpage/%2Fapex%2FMap`. There is no /sfdcpage/ in our URL.

Comment: Is their any specific permission or setting to be enabled to view VF pages in community?

Comment: Karthik , any finding on this ?

Answer (score 0):

for me

```
$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({ 
            "url": "/apex/Map" 
        }).fire();
```

didn't work.

I used this code in Lighting Component from where I am calling my VF page which is rendering in PDF and it worked

```
var inputURL = window.location.origin;
var myPDFpage ='';
myPDFpage = inputURL+'/communityurl?parameters='+parameters;
var pdfObj = document.createElement("a");
pdfObj.href = myPDFpage;
pdfObj.target="_blank";
pdfObj.click();
```